# Extract action/task from text using nltk

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

Hi i am using nltk first time  and i want  to Extract action/task  from text using nltk

```
Hi prakash, how are you ?. We need to complete the speech to action by 8 June  then you will have to finish the UI by 15 july
```

Above here the **speech to action** and **UI**  is the action.

I have started the token creation, don't know what to do next, Please guide.

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize
sample_text ="""Hi prakash, how are you ?. We need to complete the speech to action demo by 8 June  then you will have to finish the Ui by 15 july"""
sentences = sent_tokenize(sample_text)
print(sentences)    import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

sample_text = """Hi prakash, how are you ?. We need to complete the speech to action by today
then you will have to finish the UI by 15 july after that you may go finish the mobile view"""
sample_text = "need to complete the speech to action by today"
tokens = word_tokenize(sample_text.lower())
# the lower is very much required, as June and june have diffrent code NN, NNP

pos_tags = pos_tag(tokens)

result = []
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    if (pos_tags[i][1] == 'VB') and (pos_tags[i][0] in ['complete','finish']):
        # Here we are looking for text like (finish, complete, done)
        owner = ''
        for back_tag in  pos_tags[:i][::-1]:
            #traverse in back direction to know the owner who will (finish, complete, done)
            if back_tag[1]=='PRP':
                owner = back_tag[0]
                break

        message = ''
        date = ''
        for messae_index , token in enumerate(pos_tags[i:],i):
            #traverse forward to know what has to be done
            if token[1]=='IN':
                for date_index, date_lookup in  enumerate(pos_tags[messae_index:],messae_index):
                    if date_lookup[1]=='NN':
                        date = pos_tags[date_index-1][0] + ' ' + pos_tags[date_index][0]
                    if date_lookup[1]=='PRP':
                        # This is trick to stop further propegation
                        # Don't ask me why i am doing this, if you are still reading then read the nest line
                        # Save futher interation as the next sentance is i/we/you
                        break
                break
            else:
                message = message + ' ' + token[0]
        result += [dict(owner=owner, message=message, date=date)]
print(result)
```

Please guide how to extract the actions(action demo, UI) from the paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using NLTK, you can get the POS tags of your tokens and come up with a regex or pattern using those tags. For example, an action will be a verb. (For better tagging, you may require `Spacy`. There is another library called `Pattern` for these purposes)

But I'm not sure if this is going to help you a lot for a scaled application.

N.B: There are well-trained Named Entity Recognizers available, you may try them.

Comment: Hi Sleeba , Thanks for your help, i have updated the code. Can review this as the complexity is too high.

Comment: Try POS regex using `Pattern` library. Again, I'm not confident that you can build a scalable solution using this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my thoughts:
If i try to identify parts of speech for your sentence using nltk.tag.pos_tag , i get below:

```
 import nltk
 from nltk.tag import pos_tag
 from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

 s = 'Hi prakash, how are you ?. We need to complete the speech to action by 8 June  then you will have to finish the UI by 15 july'
 tokens = word_tokenize(s)
 print(pos_tag(tokens))
```

Output:

```
[('Hi', 'NNP'), ('prakash', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('how', 'WRB'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('?', '.'), ('.', '.'), ('We', 'PRP'), ('need', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('complete', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('speech', 'NN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('action', 'NN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('8', 'CD'), ('June', 'NNP'), ('then', 'RB'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('have', 'VB'), ('to', 'TO'), ('finish', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('UI', 'NNP'), ('by', 'IN'), ('15', 'CD'), ('july', 'NN')]
```

If you observe, every action word i.e. "speech to action" or "UI" occur after a preceding verb tag i.e 'complete' and 'finish' respectively.

I would suggest to try this problem with below steps:

1) Find verb in a sentence.(something like below)

```
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    if pos_tag(tokens)[][1] == 'VB':
```

2) If found, then fetch the next words based on their pos tags. (may be retrieve all next words until you find 'IN' tag)

This may work for your dataset.

Comment: Hi aditya, Thanks for your help, i have updated the code. Can review this as the complexity is too high.